# Generate same random sequence

Tags: r, sas

I want to generate the same random number in R using "sample" function and SAS using "factors" function,based on the same seed.But I got different result like this.

R code:

```
RNGkind()
#"Mersenne-Twister" "Inversion" 
set.seed(123)
sample(c(1:6),6)
2 4 6 3 5 1
```

R results:

[image: R results]

SAS code:

```
PROC plan seed = 123;
factors r = 6 random;
run;
```

SAS results:

[image: SAS results]

Whether the random number generation algorithm is different between R and SAS?

Comment: Do not post pictures, post your code and results as text.

Comment: I am sorry.I will edit this right now.

Comment: I suspect different seeds are generated. Can you check R's `.Random.seed` against the SAS equivalent? (Don't know if SAS even encodes the seed in the same way.)

Comment: Ultimately, I think trying to reproduce the exact same pseudo-random numbers in different statistical software is a doomed endeavor. Better to use the same RNG implementation. E.g., you could interface with random.org (see R package `random`) where you can get a "true" random sequence with a time stamp for reproducibility.